# sql server backup script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have made an attempt at writing a backup script for one of my very small sql server express 2008 database. 
My requirements are to do a full backup every night, keep the last five backups. This is my attempt at writing one and would like to get feedback on whether i am doing it right? 
Thanks for your assistance.

```
    declare @backupfilename nvarchar(100)
    set @backupfilename='c:\...location..\filename_'+convert(varchar(10),getdate(),112) + '.bak'

    BACKUP DATABASE [dbname] TO  DISK = @backupfilename 
    WITH  RETAINDAYS = 5, NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'Full Database Backup Name', NOSKIP,
    NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
    GO
    declare @backupSetId as int
    select @backupSetId = position from msdb..backupset where database_name=N'dbname'
    and backup_set_id=(select max (backup_set_id) from msdb..backupset where 
    database_name=N'dbname' )
    if @backupSetId is null begin raiserror(N'Verify failed. Backup information for database  
    ''dbname'' not found.', 16, 1) end
    RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM  DISK =@backupfilename  WITH  FILE = @backupSetId,  NOUNLOAD,  NOREWIND
    GO
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I highly recommend [Ola's backup stored procedures](http://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html).  They are well supported and extremely solid.  If you don't feel comfortable using them you can at least look to them while you write your own routine.

Comment: This is a highly regarded link and considered an industry standard by many... plus one.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this site..this has lot of information and i think i should be able to customize databasebackup.sql file according to my requirements...